# How to get remaining time of a shell script execution?

Tags: shell

I have a script which do different things as per the requirement.
It takes options from the user and execute the commands accordingly.
So the question is how can i find the remaining time of total execution.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot even take a *bad guess* as to what this question is asking...

Comment: If i am copying one file i can see 13 mins remaining or something like that...

Comment: so same thing i want to do with the scripts...like remaining time of the script to complete is X mins..

Comment: Figure out what you've done so far, figure out what's left, figure out how long you've taken, and build a ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to make an estimate of how much time each command will take before you run them and then subtract from the total as each command completes.

You can improve on this by readjusting the total and remaining time when each command completes based on the difference between your estimate and the actual time.

To get it even sharper, you can record times over invocations and use that to make a better guess but I think that would be overkill for just a script.

It's not possible however to get it exactly correct. Cf. http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: Okay...i'll try it!!...I thought their may be some utility or command that can do this..

Comment: You will get better estimates if you use a weighted running average... that will smooth out variations, but will not let large  variations have too much effect over the course of the run.